# Java: SplashScreen - Setting it up

Tags: java, loading, splash-screen

I want show an image/gif while my program is loading at boot. When the loading is finished, I want the image to close and the program begins as usual. I heard about SplashScreen and I put this method in the beginning of the program:

```
    public static void splashPage() {
     final SplashScreen splash = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();
        if (splash == null) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "");
            return;
        }
        Graphics2D g = splash.createGraphics();
        if (g == null) {
            System.out.println("g is null");
            return;
        }
     }
```

How should I do this? Is it allowed to have `JOptionPane`? If so, how do I make it close down when the program is done loading?

Comment: What do you mean with finish loading? Is the program straight-forward reading all the code?

Comment: Well, I want it to show while the program is reading a .txt file. I was wondering to put something like `*END*` in the end of the txt file, but I do not know how to set this whole thing up.

Answer (score 0):

launch4j - Splash Screen can be added by software

Comment: What do you mean? Could you please elaborate?